# Error fatal: pathspec '*?' did not match any files when tried to run git add * from script

Tags: bash, git, shell, sh

I am getting error as `fatal: pathspec '*?' did not match any files` when trying to run the `git add *` command from the shell script. Please find the details below.

```
OABLN1234:/mnt/d/Git_Repos/pipeline$ ll
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 1 harman harman  512 Feb 19 21:05 ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 harman harman  512 Feb 19 14:56 ../
drwxrwxrwx 1 harman harman  512 Feb 19 21:18 .git/
-rwxrwxrwx 1 harman harman 3906 Feb 19 18:39 Jenkinsfile*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 harman harman   66 Feb 19 21:18 push.sh*

OABLN1234:/mnt/d/Git_Repos/pipeline$ cat push.sh
git add *
git commit -m "Push everything from Laptop"
git push

OABLN1234:/mnt/d/Git_Repos/pipeline$ ./push.sh
fatal: pathspec '*?' did not match any files
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   push.sh

no changes added to commit
' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
        push
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you run `git add *` normally, by hand?

Comment: Have you tried running `sh ./push.sh` instead?

Comment: Does changing to `git add .` changes the behavior?

Comment: `cat -v push.sh` to verify there are no hidden strange characters after `git add *`

Comment: Your script almost certainly has DOS line endings, and the carriage return at the end of `git add *` is being shown as a `?` in the error message.

Comment: The error message `' is not a git command` also comes from the attempt to run `git push\r`, not `git push`; the carriage return corrupts how the error message is displayed.

Comment: @phd Yes it was due to DOS line endings as I written script in windows and tried to execute in linux